# What argument should i put in google translate api request body?

Tags: javascript, google-translate, google-translation-api

```
try {
const response = await fetch(googleTranslateApi + apiKey, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           charset: 'UTF-8',

     },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        requests: [
          {
            q: 'Hello My Friend',
            target: 'zh',

           }

          ]
    })
});
const responseJson = await response.json();
```

I'm trying to call the google translate API, but I keep getting this error:

> error: {code: 400, message: "Missing required field target", errors: Array(1), status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}

what am I missing from the request body?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here's a pro-tip that will make it easier for others to answer your questions: paste your code directly into the question (formatted properly using tripe tick marks (e.g. ```) on the line before and after your code). Images of code are discouraged. If someone wanted to try to run your code, they would have to type it out themselves rather than just copy and paste.

Comment: Not sure if my answer is relevant to the specific API you are trying to hit. What documentation are you looking at? Or what URL are you trying to hit?

Comment: I'm looking at their official documentation https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text
This is my first time writing a request

Comment: Perfect. Having links to documentation that you're trying to follow is another great thing to include in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have the right data in your request body, just formatted incorrectly. You have the `q` and `target` properties nested inside an object that's inside an array that's inside your top-level request body object. Instead, put the `q` and `target` properties directly inside your top-level request body object, like this:

```
try {
const response = await fetch(googleTranslateApi + apiKey, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           charset: 'UTF-8',

     },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      q: 'Hello My Friend',
      target: 'zh'
    })
});
const responseJson = await response.json();
```

Comment: I appreciate the gratitude, however—and I know it's a little strange—"thank you" comments are also discouraged, so that comments can be focused on clarifying questions and answers. Gratitude is best expressed by upvoting answers and questions that you find helpful and clicking the check mark on answers that satisfy the questions you ask (thanks for doing that by the way). I hope you continue to participate in the Stackoverflow community. Getting started can sometimes be a little confusing. You can find more tips and helpful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help.